# jQuery events close too quickly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web

The following is my jQuery code:

```
$("#remove").click(function(e) {
    $.confirm({
        'title': 'Delete Confirmation',
        'message': 'You are about to delete this item. <br />It cannot be restored at a later time! Continue?',
        'buttons': {
            'Yes': {
                'class': 'blue',
                'action': function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        'url': "../api/removeHost.php?id=" + $("#id").val(),
                        'success': function(d) {
                            var json = JSON.parse(d);
                            //Display error text
                            if (json[0] == 0) {
                                createMessageDialog("General Error", json[1][1]);
                                //If all is successful reload the listServersBody to reflect the new changes and create the success popup
                            } else {
                                $("#listBody").load(lastPopulateAPICall); //Refresh the search\browse list with the new edits/
                                enableAdd();
                                createMessageDialog("Success", "Successfully removed!");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            'No': {
                'class': 'gray',
                'action': function() {} // Nothing to do in this case. You can as well omit the action property.
            }
        }
    });
});....

function createMessageDialog(title, message) {
    $.confirm({
        'title': title,
        'message': message,
        'buttons': {
            'Ok': {
                'class': 'blue',
                'action': function() {
                    alert('dd');
                }
            },
            'No': {
                'class': 'gray',
                'action': function() {} // Nothing to do in this case. You can as well omit the action property.
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The createMessageDialog() function is being called because debugging alerts i removed were being fired.  It's just as if the box doesn't have enough time to display before the first one closes or something.  I even copied the first confirm dialog into the createMessageDialog function to no avail.  I am using the following confirm plugin http://tutorialzine.com/2010/12/better-confirm-box-jquery-css3/

Answer (score 0):

Probably the default action of what you are clicking is refreshing the page.

```
$("#remove").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel the click
    ...
```

Comment: Didnt work.  I am not refrshing the page.  I think it's because the first confirm is fading out and finishes before the next one can load

Comment: So you are saying the first shows up and the issue is when you click the Yes button?

Comment: Yes createMessageDialog() is being called however the box does not appear.

Comment: I need a functionality similar to $.ajax's success attribute.  Once everything is complete it runs a function

Comment: call it with the callback of load()?

Comment: Im very new to jQuery could you please provide a demonstration.